# I need to find an element that contains a particular text. How can I make the text a variable and pass it to the xpath function?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

````
      ```
    if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Mr"))
        {
         driv.mr.click();
        }
        else if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Mrs"))

        {
         driv.mrs.click();
        }
       else
        {
         driv.miss.click();
        }

      ```
````

#object.java#

```
  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//label[text()='Mr']" )
   public WebElement mr;
   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//label[text()='Mrs']" )
   public WebElement mrs;
   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//label[text()='Miss']" )
   public WebElement miss;
```

Here instead of passing 3 paths, I need to pass single XPath.Is there any way to do that???

Comment: hi, your question is not written very clearly - please edit your code so it formats right (check how to write markdown if you need to) and make sure you write what you want to achieve, what you have tried, and what problems you're facing. after editing, the community can assist better :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create shuch kind of method, and pass argument text to click on the needed element

```
public void clickOnButton(String text){
       WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text() = '"+text+"']")); 
       button.click();
      }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with the page factory?

Comment: I think no because argument must be constant when you are using @FindBy annotation

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.format()`

So you want something like this:

`String selector = "//label[text()='%s']";`

Then you could just do `WebElement mr = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(String.format(selector, "Mr")));`

format will automatically take the content of the second argument, and put it in place of the %s.

Comment: Can I use @FindBy annotation in here?

Comment: I don't really see any reason you're using @FindBy in this scenario. Why not just use `WebElement mr = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(String.format(selector, "Mr")));`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` in xpath to perform OR operation e.g.

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//label[text()='Mr'] | //label[text()='Mrs'] | //label[text()='Miss']" )
public WebElement prefix;
```

This will return your element if any condition satisfy out of 3.